# Android ProgressDialog inside Asynctask and RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, progressdialog

guys i have a little problem with my progressDialog. It doesn't work in correct way. My progressDialog is inside RecylerView Adapter because i load many pictures using Glide. It was only way to show progressDialog when i use Glide - if i move progressDialog to Asynctask proExecute and postExecute it only show when doinBackground job is doing and hide. But Glide still loading pictures.
As i wrote, my solution to put it inside adapter and with hide until pictures load, work strange. Sometimes when i run app i have to wait until pic load without progressdialog, sometimes it show for short time. How to solve it? What is the best way to use progressDialog in my situation?

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> shopsNames;
    ArrayList<RowModel> rowModels;

    public Realm mRealm;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar_layout)
    CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.app_bar)
    AppBarLayout appBar;
    private ShopsAdapter adapter;
    @BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ConnectionDetector connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(this);
        if (!connectionDetector.isConnection()) {
            finish();
        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);



        rowModels = new ArrayList<>();
        shopsNames = new ArrayList<>();
        Realm.init(this);

        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        initCollapsingToolbar();

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.shoplogo).
                into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop));

        adapter = new ShopsAdapter(MainActivity.this, shopsNames);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        AsyncTaskRetro asyncTaskRetro = new AsyncTaskRetro();
        asyncTaskRetro.execute();
    }

    private class AsyncTaskRetro extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            PlacesAPI.Factory.getInstance().getPlaces().enqueue(new Callback<Places>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Places> call, Response<Places> response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getPosts().size(); i++) {
                        RowModel rowModel = new RowModel(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getNazwa(),
                                Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getSzer()),
                                Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getDlug()));
                        rowModels.add(rowModel);
                    }
                    String oldName;
                    oldName = rowModels.get(0).getName();
                    shopsNames.add(rowModels.get(0).getName());

                    mRealm.beginTransaction();
                    mRealm.copyToRealm(rowModels);
                    mRealm.commitTransaction();

                    for (int j = 0; j < rowModels.size(); j++) {

                        if (rowModels.get(j).getName().equals(oldName)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        oldName = rowModels.get(j).getName();
                        shopsNames.add(rowModels.get(j).getName());
                    }

                    //sortowanie listy z nazwami sklepow
                    Collections.sort(shopsNames);

                    adapter = new ShopsAdapter(MainActivity.this, shopsNames);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Places> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    }

    private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

        // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class ShopsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    List<String> shopsList;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
    }

    public ShopsAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> shopsList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.shopsList = shopsList;

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.shop_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        shopsList.get(position);
        try {
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Czekaj...");
            String stringformat = String.format("http://www.wp.pl%s.png", shopsList.get(position));
            Glide.with(mContext).load(stringformat).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Log.d("fsfsdf", e.getMessage());
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    return false;
                }
            }).centerCrop().fitCenter().into(holder.thumbnail);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Glide.with(mContext).load("http://www.wp.pl/Zabka.png").centerCrop().fitCenter().into(holder.thumbnail);
        }

        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Log.d("Nazwa sklepu: ", shopsList.get(position));
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MapActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("shopName", shopsList.get(position));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shopsList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to show progressbar behind the imageview. Add both ImageView and ProgressBar to RelativeLayout. When image will be loaded it will automatically hide the progressbar. Shortcut :D

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just load image and don't do anything about progressbar.

Comment: great, but how to get notified when image has been loaded?

Comment: No need for that. It will look like its gone after image will be loaded on top of it.

Comment: could you show sample how this layout should look like? I'm confused and i can't imagine how it works...

Comment: i don't believe that it wil be work:) but i check this out for a moment..

Comment: not work's. Even if images load, progressDialog still show

Comment: Not possible. I have done this by myself. Image will hide the progressBar. I have checked before answering this. ProgreeDialog or ProgressBar?

Comment: Progressdialog it you want i share u tomorrow on github my project to test by your self

Comment: Sure add it to github